# Texture doesn't draw correct

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, sfml

I'm writing a game using SFLM and Opengl but when I create a terrain i got some OpenGl problems. I use heightmaps to generate a terrain but when I load the texture on it the texture is not correct mapped on the terrain. I use buffers to draw the terrain and the textures.

The code for loading the terrain:

```
void Terrain::loadTerrain(tstring filename) {

sf::Image* image = new sf::Image();

if (!image->loadFromFile(_T("GameData/Image/") + filename))
{
    Error::writeMessage("Terrain Class: Can't read file GameData/Image/" + filename);
}

size_ = sf::Vector2i(image->getSize().x, image->getSize().y);

hs_ = new float*[size_.y];
for (int i = 0; i < size_.y; i++) {
    hs_[i] = new float[size_.x];
}

normals_ = new sf::Vector3f*[size_.y];
for (int i = 0; i < size_.y; i++) {
    normals_[i] = new sf::Vector3f[size_.x];
}

//l was height
for (int y = 0; y < size_.y; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size_.x; x++) {
        sf::Color color = image->getPixel(x, y);

        float h = float(color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0f / 15.0f;
        setHeight(x, y, h);
    }
}

delete image;
computeNormals();
```

}

The source for loading the image and convert it to Opengl textures:

```
   void Terrain::loadTexture(tstring filename, Layer layer)
{
    GLuint texture = 0;
    {
        sf::Image image;
        if (!image.loadFromFile(_T("GameData/Texture/") + filename))
        {
            Error::writeMessage("Terrain Class: Can't read file GameData/Texture/" + filename);
        }
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    }

    if (textures_.size() != 0)
    {
        map<Layer, GLuint>::iterator it = textures_.find(layer);

        if (it != textures_.end())
        {
            glDeleteTextures(1, &(it->second));
        }

        textures_.insert(pair < Layer, GLuint>(layer, texture));
    }
    else
    {
        textures_.insert(pair < Layer, GLuint>(layer, texture));
    }
}
```

I create the buffers with this method:

```
void Terrain::createBuffers()
{
    vhVertexCount = 2 * size_.x * (size_.y - 1);
    sf::Vector3f* vhVertices = new sf::Vector3f[vhVertexCount];
    sf::Vector3f* vhNormal = new sf::Vector3f[vhVertexCount];
    sf::Vector2i* vhTexCoords = new sf::Vector2i[vhVertexCount];

    bool texture = true;
    int nIndex = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < size_.y - 1; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size_.x; x++)
        {
            sf::Vector3f normal = getNormal(x, z);
            if (texture)
            {
                vhTexCoords[nIndex] = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                vhTexCoords[nIndex] =  sf::Vector2i(1, 0);
            }

            vhVertices[nIndex] = sf::Vector3f((float) x, getHeight(x, z), (float) z);
            vhNormal[nIndex] = sf::Vector3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
            nIndex++;

            normal = getNormal(x, z + 1);

            if (texture)
            {
                vhTexCoords[nIndex] = sf::Vector2i(0, 1);
                texture = !texture;
            }
            else
            {
                vhTexCoords[nIndex] = sf::Vector2i(1, 1);
                texture = !texture;
            }

            vhVertices[nIndex] = sf::Vector3f((float) x, getHeight(x, z + 1), (float) z + 1);
            vhNormal[nIndex] = sf::Vector3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
            nIndex++;
        }
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vhVertexCount * sizeof(sf::Vector3f), vhVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &normalBuffer_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vhVertexCount * sizeof(sf::Vector3f), vhNormal, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &textCoordBuffer_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textCoordBuffer_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vhVertexCount * sizeof(sf::Vector2i), vhTexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    delete [] vhVertices;
    vhVertices = nullptr;

    delete [] vhNormal;
    vhNormal = nullptr;

    delete [] vhTexCoords;
    vhTexCoords = nullptr;
}
```

And finally the method to render everyting on the screen:

```
void Terrain::drawObject(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    if (!buffersCreated_)
    {
        createBuffers();
        buffersCreated_ = true;
    }

    glPushMatrix();

    float scale = 5.0f / max(size_.x - 1, size_.y - 1);
    glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
    glTranslatef(-(float) (size_.x - 1) / 2, 0.0f, -(float) (size_.y - 1) / 2);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_.find(Layer::Mid)->second);


    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textCoordBuffer_);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, (char *) NULL);

    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer_);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (char *) NULL);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (char *) NULL);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vhVertexCount);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Below there is an image from the scene. You can see that there is no texture on the terrain buth only one green color. How can I fix this issue?
[image: Texture on terrain porblem]

Comment: I think you need to keep your sf::Image alive.

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but in this line:

```
if (!image.loadFromFile(_T("GameData/Texture/") + filename))
```

if your `_T()` is the one from WinAPI, `filename` is implicitly cast to a `TCHAR*`, and this will end up adding two `TCHAR*`s, giving you a bad address. Try `tstring(_T("GameData/Texture/")) + filename`.

Comment: That's not the problem. The image is loading correct. But when I map it on the terrain there goes something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `GL_REPEAT` into `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`
if this one couldn't solve the problem then check the texture coordinates properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).